# Unable to retrive node name in javatree using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I am facing problem in order to take the node name value from java tree in teamcenter application.

When I am recording the javatree its getting recorded as javawindow().javatree().expand “;”

Name is not specified as property value for any of the nodes.

I am trying to use native methods on javatree using object property but not able to figure out how to use the native methods.

I tried using .object.getitem,object.getitems,object.getchildren but was unsucessful to retrive the name of the node value.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: Please provide information of: what have you already tried? the code that is not working? What error are you seeing. Consider reading information on "how to ask good quality questions" before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaWindow().JavaTree().Select "#0"

JavaWindow().JavaTree().Select "#0;#0"
```

methods works